# Pine script Barcolor, How to keep the first occurance of the conditions instead of coloring all the bars?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i'm trying to use the following code. but the problem is it plots a lot .. how do i just plot the first occurance of each condition

i'm trying the following code

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script"overlay = true)
rcan = input(false,"Rcan")

bR = close > close[1] and low > low[1] and high > high[1]
Rb = close < close[1] and low < low[1] and high < high[1]
rcol = bR ? color.green : Rb ? color.red : na
barcolor(rcan ? rcol : na)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change(`) function in `Pine Scrip`t to detect the first occurrence of a condition and apply the desired color to only that bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the condition was `false` on the previous bar and `true` on the current bar.

```
bR = close > close[1] and low > low[1] and high > high[1]
Rb = close < close[1] and low < low[1] and high < high[1]

bR_new = not bR[1] and bR
Rb_new = not Rb[1] and Rb

rcol = bR_new ? color.green : Rb_new ? color.red : na
```